# Re-validate input on SELECT element's change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing an AngularJS app and in this app there is a domain-management tool.
When a domain is selected, I generate the domain-records in a table, letting the user edit each row. Since the fields are dynamically created, I use ng-form to enable validating each row individually, since they share the same name.

Each domain-record has a content field where an IP, CNAME, or such resides. I validate this field using a regex pattern generated from a function based on which record type is selected (A, CNAME, TXT, etc.).

The problem is that when I edit let's say, an A record, then change the record-type to CNAME, the form still appears valid since no new validation of the content-field has been performed. The only way for me to re-validate it is to start typing in the content field which then works fine.

Check images below:

I press edit on the A record and everything looks fine:
[image]

I change the record type to CNAME and the form still appears valid even though the regex changed. When I change the type I want the content (1.2.3.4) to be re-validated since it's a new regex in place:
[image]

I start typing in the content field and now the form correctly becomes invalid. I want this to happen when I change the record-type, not only when I start typing again:
[image]

```
#Slim version of the template to give you an idea on whats going on
<form novalidate name="recordForm" class="css-form" ng-controller="EditRecordCtrl">

    <table>

        <tr ng-repeat="record in domain.data.0" class="gradeA">

            <td ng-init="startingTypeData = record.type" class="domains-td" ng-switch on="record.edit">
                <span ng-switch-default>{{record.type}}</span>
                <span ng-switch-when="true">
                    <select ng-change="domainRecordContentType(record.type)" ng-init="domainRecordContentType(record.type)" ng-model="record.type" ng-options="c for c in domainRecordTypes" class="span12">
                    </select>
                </span>
            </td>

            <td ng-init="startingContentData = record.content" class="domains-td validation-dropdown-error-parent" ng-switch on="record.edit">
                <span ng-switch-default>{{record.content}}</span>
                <span ng-switch-when="true">
                    <ng-form name="innercContentForm">
                        <span class="validation-dropdown-error" ng-show="innercContentForm.content.$error.pattern">
                            {{ 'RECORD_EDIT_FORM_RECORD_CONTENT_PATTERN_MSG' | translate }} ( {{ record.type }} )
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="record.content" name="content" required class="span12 edit-record-input" ng-pattern="domainRecordContentRegex.0" required />
                    </ng-form>
                </span>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</form>
```

How can I re-validate the input field when I change the drop-down menu?

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VAR5ho
Note! Small bug not showing the A record in the first row. You can still test the issue tho as I did in the images above.

## Update using Thomas custom directive

Before chaning dropdown
[image]

After change first dropdown from A to CNAME all content fields are wiped
[image]

## Update save button

```
<button ng-disabled="recordForm.$invalid" ng-switch-when="true" ng-if="hideRecordType(record.type)" ng-click="recordForm.$valid && editRecord(record, domainId); record.edit=false; $parent.startingNameData=record.name; $parent.startingTypeData=record.type; $parent.startingContentData=record.content; $parent.startingTTLData=record.ttl; $parent.startingPrioData=record.prio" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-icon" ><i></i>{{ 'DOMAINS_SAVE_BUTTON' | translate }}</button>
```

## Last update.. odd behavior regarding compiled element

I press edit and it goes into my normal edit view
[image]

I start typing a new IP address until it becomes valid
[image]

If I make the content invalid after being valid once, like adding a dot the value gets wiped out. Why?
[image]

Current directive based on Thomas code:

```
domainModule.directive('revalidate', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
              var reg = scope.$parent.domainRecordContentRegex[0];

              if(!$(element).parent().parent().next().find('ng-form').find('input').val().match(reg)){

                  $compile($(element).parent().parent().next().find('ng-form').children('input[name="content"]').removeClass('ng-valid-pattern'))(scope);
                  $compile($(element).parent().parent().next().find('ng-form').children('input[name="content"]').addClass('ng-invalid-pattern'))(scope);

              }

            });
        }
    };
});
```

I select the actual field now and change the class to make it invalid if the regex dont match. This way the Save button also gets invalid. This works when changing in the dropdown, but it corrupts the compiled element somehow.

Comment: Can you make a plunker or fiddle for this?

Comment: I added a plunker example in the bottom of my question. It as a small bug where the first record content fields gets wiped out due the regex. This doesnt happen in the real version but I didnt put more time into fixing that, you can still test the problem out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to create your own validation directive:

```js
.directive('myValidRec', function () {
  var genRegex = function(type){ //...
  };
  return {
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {

      var validate = function(data){
        var regex = genRegex(scope.$eval(attrs.myValidRec));
        if(regex){
          ngModel.$setValidity('record', regex[0].test(data));  
        }
        return data;
      };

      // triggers validation when the model value changes
      ngModel.$formatters.push(validate);
      ngModel.$parsers.push(validate);

      // triggers validation when the user changes the record type
      scope.$watch(attrs.myValidRec,function(){
        validate(scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This allows for a much cleaner markup:

```
<td>
  <select ng-model="record.type" ng-options="c for c in types">
  </select>
</td>

<td>
  <ng-form name="innercContentForm">
    <span ng-show="innercContentForm.content.$error.record">
      Pattern error ( {{ record.type }} )
    </span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="record.content" name="content" 
           my-valid-rec="record.type" required />
  </ng-form>
</td>
```

Check out this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QzQdYN?p=preview

Comment: This is just brilliant, worked like a charm! Thank you joakimbl!

Answer (score 4):

To trigger validation, in ng-change of select set the value of input to its value. Change line 44 in your plunker to

```
<select ng-change="domainRecordContentType(record.type);innercContentForm.content.$setViewValue(innercContentForm.content.$viewValue)" ng-init="domainRecordContentType(record.type)" ng-model="record.type" ng-options="c for c in types">
```

Updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/D1AFHi

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102401/69362

Comment: Oh god you're a STAR ! Thx ! My brain will bur with my solution :)

Comment: This was a very simple solution, I like it. My real template and plunker differs slightly though. Look in the top of my post for the slim template example. I tried this in my real version and it didnt work. Might be because of ng-switch?

Comment: Oh @JoakimB i'm sorry for you lol i hope that you can get a solution simpler than mine

Comment: Deepak N, could you comment on my question above?

Comment: @JoakimB, It would be easier to debug if you can reproduce the issue by updating the plunker to use ng-switch similar your original code.

Comment: Deepak N, Here is an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HyoCwk?p=preview . This is more or less identical to the real code. I can edit and update specific rows. When the ng-switch is present, your solution dont seem to work. Hopefully you can tell me why :)

Comment: @JoakimB As you guessed, the issue was due to ng-switch. This happens since the form created only after you click on edit. The validation works fine if the form is moved outside ng-switch-when. Have a look at line 51 in the updated plunker with this fix http://plnkr.co/edit/6O3B0x?p=preview.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Smart. Now we have two working examples of the problem in this thread. I'll upvote this answer since I already approved joakimbl's answer. Thank you Deepak N.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a directive on drop-down menu like that :

```
angular.module('App').directive('revalidate', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
          var reg = scope.$parent.domainRecordContentRegex[0];
          if(!$(element).parent().next().find('ng-form').find('input').val().match(reg)){
              $compile($('button[type="submit"]').attr('ng-disabled', "true"))(scope);  
          }

        });
      }
    }
});
```

In this directive you're watching the value of the model for the drop-down menu or the element that takes the directive.

If the value change the directive will take the value of the input and check is this value match the regEx pattern define in your controller. If not you call the $compile method to re-set the ng-disabled attribute to the submit button.

The valid is here again.

Look at the docs to understand the $compile in details : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Hope it helps if you need more help ask it :) i'll happy to help you again ;) !

Happy coding

**UPDATE :**

Ok so if you $compile your input the value of the input is lost because the value is not persost on the scope yet ...

So to keep the value of your input if you $compile it do like that :

```
angular.module('App').directive('revalidate', function($compile, $timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
          var reg = scope.$parent.domainRecordContentRegex[0];
          if(!$(element).parent().next().find('ng-form').find('input').val().match(reg)){
              var value = $(element).parent().next().find('ng-form').find('input').val();
              $compile($(element).parent().next().find('ng-form').find('input').attr('ng-class', "ng-invalid-pattern"))(scope);
              $timeout(function(){
                $(element).parent().next().find('ng-form').find('input').val(value);
              }, 0);
          }

        });
      }
    }
});
```

Here you stock the value of your input in the "value" var and then after the $compile you're doing a $timeout with a delay of 0.

In this $timeout (that return a promise ---> The asynchronism powerful XD) you re-set the value of your input and voila !!

Comment: Maybe you'll have bugs because i can test the plunker (i'm at office and i've got a big big proxy). But this is the right way ! Say me if you have troubles

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for replying. I tried your code. Problem is that the form has dynamicly created fields, using nested form "ng-form" for each row. If I am editing two separate rows, your code revalidates everything, not just the row that I am currecntly editing. I updated the main question with an image to demostrate what happens with your code.

Comment: Yes he revalidates everything because my selector takes all the input. You have to do your personal selector

Comment: I'll do for the wiped :) check the new code he revalidate only one input

Comment: Looking allot better. Now however, when I change from A to lets say CNAME and start typing in the field, the content-field wipes itself when Iam typing.. like www.some-domain. <- then it goes blank. I cant see in your code when this is happening

Comment: Now should be work sorry it's a mistake of my part. But you got a bug on the regexp, if you do a concole.log of reg var you will see that for SRV or TXT it's the samle. I think that the boolean param of the regexp is ignored. But it's not the same matter

Comment: SRV and TXT should be the same. However, the "Save" button still disapears when it $compiles.. :( I noticed though that the real save button and the on in the plunker differs abit. I added an update on the real on in the main question. Might help?

Comment: It disappears with the ng-switch ! It's pretty normal ! Do you really need it ?

Comment: If you want to keep it : just try to compile the parent where the ng-switch attribute is o before compile the ng-disabled

Comment: Hi Thomas, Iam currently trying to understand $compile to be able to adapt your example to my needs. Hopefully ill crack the nut soon. It's still abit shady how this is actually helping me so bare with me.

Comment: Hmm.. this just dont seem to comply with ng-switch which I use. When it compiles the button disapears, most likly because the changed element(button) cant read the ng-switch varible anymore after compilation. Tips on how to manage this?

Comment: Have you try this : $compile($('button[type="submit"]').attr('ng-switch-when', "true"))(scope); and the same thing on the element which get the ng-switch attribute on the attibute ng-switch of course. Anyway i think that this is another problem you should open a new question IMHO this question is resolved

Comment: Iam gonna accept this answer in a few beacuse it seems to be the best option available. However, I did some modifications to fit my needs and I get some really odd behavior that I cannot explain.. check update in my main question in the bottom. Know whats going on?

Comment: the value gets wiped because the $compile function reset your input... that's why

Comment: AHAHAH ! If you want to keep the value of the input you can use $timeout like that after $compile like that see : $timeout(function(){
                $(element).parent().next().find('ng-form').find('input').val(value);
              }, 0);    Do you see ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to watch "record.type" model and on change of it, trigger ur new regex validation. But in order to do that the model "record.content" has undergo a change which you can perform through code.